# Sharepoint Online - always in site preview

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online

I got a problem with sharepoint online. I'm testing to create a own masterpage. Yesterday I made some mistakes and get only error warnings (On masterpage was standard). So I switched in Sharepoint Designer 2013 to Oslo Theme.

I don't no why, but if I start Sharepoint now, I get the hole time the Preview Site from Oslo. I checked the Design Manager. There ist Oslo the standard theme. I set in Sharepoint Designer 2013 the Oslo.html as standard.

I have realy no idea, why Sharepoint is loading the Preview by default.

Regards.
wit4r7

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution by myself.

In Sharepoint Designer go to "Site Pages" and set Homepage.aspx as default.